# A black hole prison?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, science-fiction

In the past a war between an entity and a race that controlled the galaxy ended when the elders of that race sacrificed themselves to imprison that entity. They trapped the entity in a 100X50 square meters prison with their bodies acting as magical seals to keep it imprisoned. The problem is if the seals are compromised in anyway the entity would be free.

There are no method of actually destroying the entity as he has magic. For an easier time imagine the sort of power that the Martian Manhunter has that makes him become like air. So all earthly and scientific methods of destroying anything will end in that entity becoming like thin air and escaping. Please I don't want to argue about the magic in my world, consider it a thing if you would. This also applies to the whole little prison as it pure magic but outside of it will obey the natural laws of science.

We have the last remaining survivor having vast futuristic abilities that correspondent to them being the remnants of their empire. They have to figure out a way to hide this prison somehow so can't be found. What they have is your own suggestions which I hope will follow what I wrote below.

**Using our understanding of science and a bit of speculative science, if you have to, can those remnants utilize a black hole in anyway to hide the prison or make it inaccessible as much as possible? If yes then how? If no then why?**

**This is a question can it be done using our science with near unlimited abilities, no need to worry about the exact details of the materials used or economy...etc**

I know it is long enough but I'll just try to make it more clear instead of wasting people's time.

- They are attempting to do their best. Perhaps 3 billion years later another empire rises to claim it and all is doomed. They are just doing their best.
- Magic is not an option like I said. Mainly because it defies a bunch of other things I made.
- They can make it of black hole resistant materials inside the black hole if it makes sense.
- They can make it just outside the black hole, what would be distance? at a certain distance if out understanding of science can't support the other options.
- Whatever option you can come up to make that prison inaccessible and/or hidden as possible while using black holes in anyway you can.
- The lack of say the remnants limitations of energy or materials...etc is again because I want to know if it can be done. The limit is our science and speculative science. It's about if it can be done not with how much energy output or what sort of materials.
- Other options are exhausted. I'm limiting this to the limitations I wrote.
- As usual I appreciate input to improve or clarify it is something is not done right.
- I'm perfectly happy if the answer is no. As long as it is detailed enough I appreciate it.

Basically I'm asking for something like: If a 1950 head of a state asked his advisors if humanity can build a space station. Does the science support it or not? Without worrying about the cost.
Obviously for them they still lack the tools to do it yet. But we know it is possible.

Comment: Nothing escapes an event horizon. The rest is magic :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so, firstly hiding IN a Black hole is something you really dont want to touch for the sacke of your Story. Thats not possible without using actual Magic. It just breaks every Law you can think of because it means Traveling FTL. Not to mention that even if you could somehow get into and out of the Event Horizion, that in and of itself would make a Black Hole a really bad place to hide.

The reason being that there is a way to go into a Black Hole and check if something is there. And the number of Black Holes is vastly lower than the one of lets say Stars. So anyone looking for this thing will probably start there.

So, if hiding in the Black Hole is out of the Question, is around it any better ? No. Same reason, people would look there first.

I dont want to tell you what you should do. If you want the thing to be in a Black Hole, do it. We dont know what happens inside a Black Hole. Saying that right after the Event Horizion you encounter a Space without any Forces is as valid as saying you enter a new Universe. We dont know, thus anything could happen.

But just be warned that a Black Hole is not a good place to hide. It is way to obvious.

Here is what I would do in your situation. Stealth.
There is no single Material that can just make you Invisable. But you can get really close.

I would build a Sphere lets say 10km across made of many META Material Layers. A META Material is basically a Fancy substance that can do cool stuff. For Example, Lightbending Materials are META.
The first layer of the Sphere would do exactly that. It would bend the EMS around it. This makes the Sphere Effectivly Invisable to the EMS. The downside is that you cannot see out. The Other layers would be there to insolate and Absorb heat. If you cant be seen by for example Radar, another way to notice you is via Heat you emit. So it needs to be an absolute priority to make the Sphere as cold as it can get. This will blend you with the CMB. Meaning the heat you emit is not visable.

This sphere by all means is Invisable. Short of just Strip Searching the entire Galaxy, nobody will see it. It cant be seen or detected. And if you place it in the void between star Clusters, it might as well be not there. The only way to find is would be Gravity. You cant really hide that. This could be the way how the find the Sphere.